# 'Autodiscover service couldn't be located': Exchange

Tags: exchange-2007

I am trying to login by exchange using following script

```
ExchangeService Service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
Service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("abc", "123456","mydomain.net");
Service.TraceEnabled = true;
Service.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
Service.AutodiscoverUrl("abc@mydomain.net");
Folder inbox = Folder.Bind(Service, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
Console.WriteLine("The folder name is " + inbox.DisplayName.ToString());
```

I am getting exception 'Autodiscover service couldn't be located'. 
Here Username and Password is correct.

---

I get the answer by following code.

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = CertificateValidationCallBack;
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
service.TraceEnabled = true;
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("abc@mydomain.net", "123456");
service.AutodiscoverUrl("abc@mydomain.net", RedirectionCallback);
string url=service.url.toString();
```

Now I want to get information of Logs and Result same like outlook provides.
Please provide me way to get it.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `Get-ClientAccessServer | Select Name, *Internal* | fl` in the Exchange Powershell to pull back what your current settings are for the URLs and post it here.

Have you checked that Autodiscover service is working properly? Go to https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/ and run the tests.

Comment: Yes. Test is successful in https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/ 
How/where to test "Get-ClientAccessServer | Select Name, *Internal* | fl" command?

Comment: Exchange Powershell.

Comment: I have windows 8 64-bit system and i have Exchange-2007. I don't get any Exchange Management Tool setup for 64-bit which support Exchange-2007. Please suggest me way to achieve this.

Comment: If you don't have access to the server, you will need to contact the admin of the server.